# MVP: should the Presenter carry out bootstrap tasks?

Tags: php, model-view-controller, mvp

I'm converting a bespoke PHP site to use MVP. This is preferable to me than MVC. Plus most of the tutorials and frameworks that claim to be MVC seem to be more MVP, in my opinion.

Anyway, my site site has a bootstrap that contains:

1. PSR-0 autoloader for namespaced classes
2. Hard-coded configuration that would never change (all in an associative array `$settings`)
3. Creation of generic objects such as database connection, variable cleaner, formatter, etc
4. Database connection
5. Loading settings from a database (editable in the CMS)
6. URL routing

In MVP would the Presenter “take over” from the bootstrap and do any of these tasks?

If I understand MVP correctly the Presenter should be a class that handles all user input so this would include URL routing. The other points, to me, seem more like the responsibility of the bootstrap. My only concern here is injecting all those objects and the settings into the Presenter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**tl;dr** Use a top-level AppController that handles routing and setup that is needed for all pages, and leave the presenter for things related to a specific page/view.

---

#### Use a top-level controller for general stuff

This [GWT MVP tutorial](http://www.gwtproject.org/articles/mvp-architecture.html) has an additional AppController that handles all things not specific to a certain view/presenter. I find this a good idea. Although GWT is for the client side, the same principle can be used on the server.

The presenter in MVP is quite specific to a certain view, and it should talk only to the view and model (or their respective interfaces), while all your items are not specific to a particular page/view. If you put it all in the "the presenter", then you are misusing the presenter like a controller in "Web MVC".

#### Example

For example, the AppController can select the correct presenter based on the HTTP parameters (i.e. routing), establish a DB connection and load other general settings. The connection object can then be passed to the presenter, which knows to instantiate the correct view and model, and pass the connection along to the model. The view and presenter should not know anything about the connection, and the model should not depend on any implementation, just have the interface injected.

#### Settings

> Loading settings from a database (editable in the CMS)

This sounds like it should belong into a model. The model knows what settings it needs and can ask for them. If the settings are related to the UI, then the presenter or view should ask for them. If it is purely visual stuff, then it would go into the view, but if it is "display logic", then it belongs into the presenter, as in MVP the view should have no logic in it.

Comment: Thanks, that's a great help. 1. From a dependency injection/unit testing point-of-view, should the generic objects mentioned in my question be injected into AppController and then into the relevant Controller or is it okay for the Controller to create them? 2. Should the Presenter and Model avoid generating any HTML? 3. What is the advantage of the Controller being a class? I can't help thinking it could just be an included PHP file. I can see why the Models would be a class. I'm guessing the View is a class that accepts the data, escapes it and then calls the template file.

Comment: 1. There has to be anyway a class/file at the top level that instantiates the objects. You can use AppController or s Factory for that.
2. Yes definitely don't generate any HTML in Presenter or Model.
3. I am not so familiar with the programming idioms of PHP, so maybe just a file is ok. Encapsulation functionality in a class makes it testable in isolation, but a class that instantiates other objects is anyway not very well testable. The View you describe is a simple one but keeps with the spirit of a "dumb" view, so it sounds ok to me.